# 2D forloop counter django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have 2D forloop in django like this:

```
        {% for temp in data.lines.all %}
            {% for item in temp.articles.all %}

                <section class="{{ counter of these loops }}" >
                    {% include "page.html" %}
                </section>

            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

now  what put in {{ counter of these loops }} place to get number of loop counter.

If the first loop has 4 elements and each element has 5 children, now at finish I also must have
 counter = 20.

Comment: That is not your code, because there is no assignment syntax in Django templates.

Comment: OK, It's just my question.I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution can be to create a counter object from a class like

```
class Counter:
    counter = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.counter += 1
    def set_to_zero(self):
        self.counter = 0
```

and pass it in the context.
Then you can increment it with

```
{{ counter.increment }}
```

But **it is ugly**, because if you have many loop you will have to pass a lot of variable in your context, and most of the time it is a bad idea to change the state of an object in the template.

Answer (score 1):

**in custom filter:**

```
def multiply_rows(value, arg):
    return value*arg
```

**in template:**

```
{{forloop.counter|multiply_rows forloop.parentloop.counter}}
```

may be your solution.